# when i try to run the app on my ipad from xcode this message appeared

Tags: xcode, swift

No provisioning profiles with valid signing identity ((certificate and private key pair )) matching the bundle identifier ((sniper.stock)) were found

Answer (score 0):

To run/test your app on a device you need an [developers license](https://developer.apple.com/programs/). when you have a license you can create a certificate and a Provisioning Profile.

Comment: i used xcode 7 beta and apple now said that Xcode 7 and Swift now make it easier for everyone to build apps and run them directly on their Apple devices. Simply sign in with your Apple ID, and turn your idea into an app that you can touch on your iPad, iPhone, or Apple Watch. Download Xcode 7 beta and try it yourself today. Program membership is not required."